# XNA/Monogame inverting a BoundingBox

Tags: xna, c#, collision-detection, monogame, bounding-boxes

I have a box that is drawn around my game that I want to check collisions with. Currently my `BoundingBox` is made in a way that whatever is **inside** the box is colliding with it:

```
BoundingBox bb = new BoundingBox(new Vector3(position.X - 0.1f, position.Y - 0.1f, position.Z - width - 0.1f), new Vector3(position.X + width + 0.1f, position.Y + width + 0.1f, position.Z + 0.1f));
```

(Note: the `+0.1f` is added so that it doesn't cause collision when an object is touching it, only when it passed through)

What I want is the inverse. I want a `BoundingBox` around this box so that only objects **outside** of the box will cause collision.

Is there an easy way of doing this or am I supposed to make different BoundingBoxes around this existing one? Thanks

Comment: I must be missing some subtlety here.  Can't you solve this problem with [the `not` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2kd6eb2.aspx)?

Comment: @SethBattin The subtlety is that the possible results of an intersection test are ternary (disjoint/intersects/contains), not binary. So applying a binary `not` operation might not give the desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BoundingBox` provides several `Contains` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.boundingbox.contains.aspx)) methods that return `ContainmentType` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.containmenttype.aspx)).

To test if an object is *outside* your bounding box, test for `ContainmentType.Disjoint`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to invert the logic of the test not the box itself. The bounding box can only describe a box. Whether that is a rectangular solid in space or a rectangular hole in infinite space is up to the test performed.